# Okular: Transform tab into separate window

Tags: okular

I usually want my PDFs to be opened in a single instance of Okular in separate tabs instead of having each PDF be opened in an independent Okular window. Therefore, I have enabled `Open new files in tabs` under Settings > Configure Okular > General.

However, at some times I would rather have one particular tab to be its own window instead. Is there a way to convert a tab to its own window in Okular or open a PDF as a separate Okular instance, even though `Open new files in tabs` is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have figured out, it is (now) possible to open a second instance of Okular with no issues, even if the `Open new files in tabs` option is enabled. Once you have the second Okular instance started, you can then simply drag&drop the respective PDF onto the Okular instance that you want to open it in.